# Query a data extension in Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there any other way to query a data extension in Marketing cloud other than doing a query activity and putting the results in a new DE. I am not sure if there is something like workbench for marketing cloud which would let me write a query and retrieve the results. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a workbench feature that would allow you to write the query and get the results directly but there are a few ways of getting data out of data extension.

1. [Query Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/)
2. [AMPscript](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookup/#Lookup) or [Server-Side JavaScript](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/data_extension_server_side_javascript_functions/) lookup
3. [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_data_from_a_data_extension.htm) utilizing a filter
4. Using the [Filter](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/creating_a_filtered_data_extension/) functionality

Answer (score 1):

Get Query Studio in the appexchange. This is like a workbench.